# Delete all files or reset phone automatically if I don't use my phone for several days

Tags: factory-reset, automation

I want to set a time limit so that if I don't use my phone within that time limit, then it will delete/reset my phone data (everything).

Moreover, if I use/unlock the phone within that time, then the counter will start from the beginning.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Not sure, but check with Tasker ?

Comment: Factory reset would need root access, or a device admin app with [delete user data feature](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminInfo.html?hl=ru#USES_POLICY_WIPE_DATA).